# Sequelize - Filter FindAll by matching all Tags

Tags: express, sequelize.js

```
/assets/?tags[]=foo&tags[]=bar
```

Get requests to endpoint above should return only those records that contain ALL of the provided tags (`foo`,`bar`)

My current attempt is returning any records that match ANY of the given tags.

```
const { tags } = req.query;

res.send(
      await Asset.findAll({
        where: whereOptions,
        include: [
          { model: AssetMime },
          {
            model: Tag,
            as: 'tags',
            where: {
              title: {
                [Op.in]: tags,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      })
    );
```

*How can I modify my filter to return records where ALL tags match?*

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Op.all` operator instead of `op.in` if your DBMS supports `ALL` operator.

An alternative solution is to combine such conditions

```
const tagWhereOptions = {}
if (tags && tags.length) {
  tagWhereOptions[Op.and] = tags.map(x => ({ title: x })
}

await Asset.findAll({
        where: whereOptions,
        include: [
          { model: AssetMime },
          {
            model: Tag,
            as: 'tags',
            where: tagWhereOptions,
          },
        ],
      })
```

Comment: I did try this but received SQL error, im guessing ALL not supported

Comment: added alternative solution

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little? I have just been reading up on Op.and and do not see how to implement in my case

Comment: let me convert this this to Typescript and see

Comment: What does it mean? What happened if you have several values?