# Filter a query through a "to many" include by a list

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 3 tables (M:M). Advertisement, Characteristic, and AdvertChar that joins them.

I want to retrieve only the advertisements that have all of the characteristics from the request. The current query returns advertisements that have at least one of the requested characteristics instead the ones that have all of them.

```
let adverts = await Advertisement.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Characteristic,
            where: { id: { [Op.in]: characteristicsFromRequestList } }
        }
    ]
});
```

Is there any way to adjust the query to suit my needs?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `Op.and` and manually combine conditions for all values like I mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63631484/1376618)

Comment: Doesn't work. When multiple characteristics are provided regardless of if they are present in the ad or not, it always returns 0 results. When a single characteristic is provided, it works as expected.

Comment: It kind of makes sense that it doesn't work when multiple id's are provided. An entry can't match multiple different unique identifiers at the same time.

Comment: Then try Op.all if your DBMS supports it